# After Upgrading to macOS High Sierra (version 10.13.1), Eclipse Neon 1a crashes on builds

Tags: eclipse, crash, macos-sierra

Eclipse neon 1a (release 4.6.1). Has anyone else been experiencing this issue? I attempt to "build all" via "command b" and every other time I execute the command Eclipse crashes.

```
Process:               eclipse [24118]
Path:                  
/private/var/folders/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:            org.eclipse.platform.ide
Version:               4.6.1 (4.6.1.M20160907-1200)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           eclipse [24118]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-11-15 13:12:14.819 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.1 (17B48)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        9FBBDD4C-868D-C2C6-D335-3056CD6A5E11

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D8ABAD67-BD34-4AFA-AE70-BCE2463C3A2F

Time Awake Since Boot: 180000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Notes:                 Translocated Process

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000138b3f2f0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the current version of Eclipse (Eclipse Oxygen.1a)?

Comment: I haven't tried with Eclipse Oxygen.1a

Comment: I have the same problem even with Oxygen 2 :(.

Comment: Has anyone been able to fix this? I have the same issue trying to run Eclipse JUNO using Java 6 on MacOS Mojave. Eclipse crashes on launch every time.